# php zip file - add new_ziparchive?

Tags: php

I need to create a zzip file , i tried a script but i get an error message:

```
Warning: ZipArchive::addFile() [ziparchive.addfile]: Invalid or unitialized Zip object
```

this is my script:

```
<?php
$path = "./downloads/";

$file = $_FILES["file"]["name"];

$zip=new ZipArchive;

$zip->addFile('./downloads/', $_FILES["file"]["name"]); 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the example [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/zip.examples.php).

You have to call the `open` method:

```
$zip->open("/path/to/filename.ext", ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE);
```

Or call the constructor in a different fashion:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive("/path/to/filename.ext", ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE);
```

Comment: please can someone just give me some help and no examples, it's easy to copy and paste i need help not help to further stupid examples

Comment: @drakos Hum? I gave you both. Links to examples **and** an explain of what was wrong/needed to be done.

Comment: sorry man i'm probably to stupid for this i am just so fedup no punn intended mate:)

Comment: don't worry i got it from another crazy site:) and it works well

Answer (score 0):

you'll need to use `$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]` not `$_FILES["file"]["name"]`

Comment: hey fire thanks man i tried this<?php 
 $zip = new ZipArchive($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE);
      $zip->addFile('./members/$id/music/', $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);
?>but it still gave me this message:Warning: ZipArchive::addFile() [ziparchive.addfile]: Invalid or unitialized Zip object